# Add new value in multiple array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-push

I was searching around but still I can't find an answer.
I have following array

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    0 => "Name"
    1 => "Age"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    0 => "Name"
    1 => "Age"
  ]
]
```

and I want to add new value `0` in all arrays. This is the result I expect.

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    0 => "Name"
    1 => "Age"
    2 => 0
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    0 => "Name"
    1 => "Age"
    2 => 0
  ]
]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Iterate over array. Add values to each element as you use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like.

```
foreach($array as &$subArray) {

     $subArray[] = 0;
}
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it only added in the last array.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :)

Comment: Its my pleasure, Enjoy. :)

Comment: why even create a new array ? you can use the original one

Comment: Yes both way its possible.